# Has anyone used Mongoose-auth? How do you over-ride findOrCreateUsers?

Tags: javascript, authentication, mongodb, node.js, mongoose

Right now I'm using mongoose-auth's Facebook Connect. Everything works fine, and users are being created/logged in through my mongodb server.

However, I want to over-ride findOrCreateUsers, because I want to assign each new user a random "code" upon signup, and put it inside their db.users profile.

So I looked into the `mongoose-auth/lib/facebook`, and I copied those 3 facebook module files into my own directory [everyauth.js, index.js, schema.js].  To run a simple test, I basically included my own everyauth.js from my directory, and used its findOrCreateUsers method instead of the default one.

It works, but there is one error.  After logging in/creating the user, `req.user` is undefined. (`req.loggedIn` shows True, yay!)

I know this is a new library, but if you've used it (or know a lot about Node.js), I'd really appreciate it if you could help me.  I'm on #node.js on irc.freenode.net.  Nickname is "**xeodox**".  If you could help me I'd really appreciate it!!

I overrode findOrCreateUser by doing this to the facebook module in my app.js:

```
 findOrCreateUser: function (sess, accessTok, accessTokExtra, fbUser) {
    var promise = new Promise()
      , self = this;
    // TODO Check user in session or request helper first
    //      e.g., req.user or sess.auth.userId
    this.User()().findOne({'fb.id': fbUser.id}, function (err, foundUser) {
      if (foundUser)
        return promise.fulfill(foundUser);
      self.User()().createWithFB(fbUser, accessTok, accessTokExtra.expires, function (err, createdUser) {
        return promise.fulfill(createdUser);
      });
    });
    return promise;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

No need to copy those files into your own directory. Just do the following in your mongoose-auth configuration:

```
facebook: {
  everyauth: {
      myHostname: 'http://localhost:3000'
    , appId: 'YOUR APP ID HERE'
    , appSecret: 'YOUR APP SECRET HERE'
    , redirectPath: '/home'
    , findOrCreateUser: function (session, accessToken, fbUserMetadata) {
      }
  }
}
```

For help on the undefined `req.user`, file an [issue](https://github.com/bnoguchi/mongoose-auth/issues) on github with a link to a self-contained [gist](https://gist.github.com) to re-create the issue, and I can help you out.